# Hash string and retrieve from hash later

Tags: php, hash

Is there any way to hash a string, and un-hash it later?

For example, I want to hash an email address to make a unique link, and retrieve the email address when the link is visited.

It's more about obfuscation than hashing, as you can see.

Comment: No you can't unhash anything. You can however encode and decode a string.

Comment: use mcrypt source: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot hash and unhash a string but can use base64_encode and base64_decode to do a similar thing:

```
<?php
$str = 'This is an encoded string';
echo base64_encode($str);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==
```

You can decode it:

```
<?php
$str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==';
echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
This is an encoded string
```

As in the PHP.net manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: Is there any way to make the encoding shorter, while still preserving its data?

Comment: Well why not create a random unique string in a database to reference the URL, then when you need the reference pull out of db to get url

Answer (score 1):

There is no unhash. hash is a one way encryption. for that purpose you can save email and hash in a table and select email where hash equals to something.

```
id, email, hash
1   a@b.cc  m3jf9s...


SELECT `email` from `activation_table` WHERE `hash` = 'm3jf9s...';
```

then display it on the page.